# passing/displaying values from JavaScript to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JS code which use's local storage to display the 'name' and 'age' entered previously:

This HTML code currently displays the date, time, name and age of a person in a table. how can i pass these values to be displayed in a HTML form as labels instead of in that table?

HTML only bringing back the start time, name and age aren't being displayed:

```
 <div id="history_list"></div>
    <div id="name"> </div>
    <div id="age"></div>
```

JS:

```
    function loadHistoryList() {

        for(var i = numberOfHistory; i >= 1; i--) {
            var historyData = new historyElement(db.getItem(i.toString()));

            if(historyData === null) {
                console.error('error');
                continue;
            }
            $('#history_list').append(historyData.startTime);
            $('#name').append(historyData.name);
            $('#age').append(historyData.age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: no this is not a homework question. yeah or course i've tried it. i have the value displaying on the HTML page but they are displaying more than once will update my question.

Comment: can you add in jsfiddle ??

Comment: Are you talking about populating the form with pre-existing data?

Comment: yeah pretty much, i just want to display the local storage on a html page

Comment: i have tried ' $('#name').append(div); $('#age').append(div);' but not sure if this i how the values should be called using divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
var div = '<div id="history_element"><div id="element_title">' + historyData.startDate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + historyData.startTime + '</div><table>';
var div = '<div id="name"><tr><td>name: </td><td>' + historyData.name+ '</td></tr>';
var div = '<div id="age"><tr><td>age: </td><td>' + historyData.age+ '</td></tr>';

div += '</table></div>';

$('#history_list').append(div);
$('#name').append(div);
$('#age').append(div);
```

Do this:

```
$('#history_list').append(historyData.startTime);
$('#name').append(historyData.name);
$('#age').append(historyData.age);
```

In short: you can (and should in this case) simply add the desired value to the container (the DIV, Form field, or whatnot)

those three lines starting witn `var div (...)` are overwriting each previous line, but that is a side note.
Overall, you should read up more on JavaScript and/or JQuery.

Comment: i've added append name and age to my JS file. tried to call them in the HTML file but the start time is the only value appearing. should i be using   <div id="name"></div> to display name value in HTML?

Comment: not sure what you mean, @userdanhas1994. With the HTML provided in your question (three `div`s) it should work fine.

Comment: please see my updated question, i have the 3 div's in my updated question but it's still only displaying the start time

Comment: @userdanhas1994 your code should work. Are you sure that `historyData.name` and `historyData.age` have values? you might try `alert (historyData.name);` to make sure those are not empty.

Comment: it was a problem with the css file i had it, works now thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To populate the form field First you have to add a form element like input field

**HTML**

```
<div id="history_list">
</div>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

**JS**

```
function loadHistoryList() {

for(var i = numberOfHistory; i >= 1; i--) {
        var historyData = new historyElement(db.getItem(i.toString()));

        if(historyData === null) {
            console.error('error');
            continue;
        }
        $('#name').val(historyData.name);
    }

}
```